# I have a problem in Fragment Page refresh after dialog is dismiss from adapter of that fragment

Tags: android

> My Dialog close

```
 if (status.equals("true")) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "" + msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    dialog.dismiss();
 }
```

**I have used notifyDataSetChanged() but still the Fragment layout is not refreshing or not updating**

> Adapter.java

```
        holder.txt_payRef_update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (orderlistArrayList.get(position).getPaymentStatus().equals("0")) {

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_payment_reference);
                Window window = dialog.getWindow();
                window.setLayout(Toolbar.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                final TextView txt_orderId = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_orderId);
                final TextView txt_total_amount = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_total_amount);
                final TextView txt_doPayment = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_doPayment);
                final TextView edtxt_order_referenece_id = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtxt_order_referenece_id);


                txt_orderId.setText("Order ID " + orderlistArrayList.get(position).getOrderId());
                txt_total_amount.setText("Total Due Amount " + (context.getResources().getString(R.string.Rs)) + orderlistArrayList.get(position).getTotalPrice());
                edtxt_order_referenece_id.setText(orderlistArrayList.get(position).getPayRef());

                txt_doPayment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        String Reference_Id = edtxt_order_referenece_id.getText().toString();
                        if (!Reference_Id.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

                            DoUpdatePaymentRef(orderlistArrayList.get(position).getOrderId(), Reference_Id);
```

//                                Toast.makeText(context, "Done!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                                dialog.dismiss();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Please Put Order Reference ID!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

```
                        }
                    }

                    private void DoUpdatePaymentRef(String orderId, String reference_id) {

                        progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
                        progress.setMessage("Please Wait..");
                        progress.setCancelable(false);
                        progress.show();
                        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
                        try {
                            params.put("orderId", orderId);
                            params.put("payRef", reference_id);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        System.out.println("Params orderPayRefUpdate--> " + params.toString());
                        System.out.println(" URL_orderPayRefUpdate--> " + Constant.orderPayRefUpdate);


                        JsonObjectRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constant.orderPayRefUpdate, params,
                                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                        String status = "";
                                        progress.dismiss();

                                        System.out.println("orderPayRefUpdate Response -->" + response.toString());
                                        try {
                                            JSONObject objStatus = new JSONObject(response
                                                    .toString());
                                            status = objStatus.getString("valid");
                                            String msg = objStatus.getString("msg");
                                            if (status != null && !status.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                                                if (status.equals("true")) {


                                                    Toast.makeText(context, "" + msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

//                                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                        dialog.dismiss();

```
                                                } else {

                                                    Toast.makeText(context, "" + msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                }
                                            }

                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            progress.dismiss();
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                            //Toast.makeText(PersonalInfo_QRActivity.this, "e." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }

                                    }
                                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                System.out.println("Error : " + error.toString());
                            }
                        });
                        jsonArrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                                30000,
                                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
                        VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).getRequestQueue()
                                .add(jsonArrayRequest);
                    }
                });


                dialog.show();

            }
        }
    });
```

> Fragment.java

```
  adapterOrderList = new AdapterOrderList(getActivity(), orderlistArrayList);
                                        adapterOrderList.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        grid_view_fragment.setAdapter(adapterOrderList);
```

Comment: Can't understand your question clearly

Comment: I have a Fragemnt class and in the xml file of the fragment class has listview. And for that listview an adapter is there & custom layout of the adapter class has a btn. btn click dialog open now updating some data of that particular list and when getting that dialog response succesfull i have close the dialog but fragment list value not updated. again when open it then getting the updated value. How to refresh that fragment xml so that will get the updated value when dialog dismiss.

Comment: Did you updated the recent data in listview arrayList?, Once you updated you should call the adapter.notifyItemchanged(position); or adapter.nitifydatasetchanged()

Comment: I have done it in my Fragment class. I am Updating it in AdapterClass so is there any code needed if success response?

Comment: Put the code in above question that you have used to update the list

Comment: check i have updated my code. added the exact what i have done. in that respose success truw i need to update the adapter class or refresh. so that i can see direct updated value

Answer (score 0):

Once you updated, you should update the values in your `orderlistArrayList`

For example if you want to update the text that you have entered in this edit text `edtxt_order_referenece_id` you should get the strign value from the edit text and you should update it in the item position `orderlistArrayList.get(position).setPayRef(edtxt_order_referenece_id.getText().toString())`

Once you have done you should call the `notifyDataSetChanged();` or `notifyItemChanged(position);`

Comment: Nope! tried with this solution but not refresh the same page

Comment: Then you are missing something may be calling adapter or updating list

Comment: i can't find out what i am missing exactly